# Webkit Wobble - Sprite Sequence Bug?

Tags: css, animation, webkit, sprite-sheet

This is something which has been annoying me for a couple days now.

I have a spritesheet used for buttons, playing the sequence on hover/click/whatever is no problem and looks great (the image in the link is just a quick example of course). Let's say I also want that sequence to reverse on mouseout, in Firefox this plays fine. In Chrome and Safari however the image seems to 'wobble' when it plays a sequence in 
reverse.

http://jsfiddle.net/SzcQn/

This example shows a quick mock up of the problem. Try mousing over the image and it will play the sequence, when you mouse out it will reverse it. In firefox this looks fine but in webkit browsers it wobbles.

The image sequence is not at fault, the code is identical for webkit and moz... I can only conclude it is a bug.

Obviously I could simply include an additional 15, in this case, frames which have the sequence reversed... but that seems a needless waste of resources.

Does anyone know of a way to resolve this issue? I have tried it with multiple sprite sheets, multiple ways of activating the animation and different webkit animation settings... the problem only occurs when it is set to play through the images from right to left, ie. in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug. Probably. I'd file it/search to see if anyone else has reported it.

Comment: I reported it on the webkit site but it seems a rather trivial issue that most people won't be bothered by so I don't expect a fix any time soon. Hopefully I can find a way round this without having to add the extra frames to the image (because clearly tolerating the minor issue is out of the question...)

Comment: Not many people are using the steps stuff, so I would expect it isn't heavily tested. Very true, minor issues are the worst though :)